# why kubelet communicate with apiserver by using TLS needs password?v1.3

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I deployed apiserver using TLS on master node and it worked fine,my question appeared when I deploying the kubelet and tring to communicate with apiserver.
the kubelet conf as follows:

```
/opt/bin/kubelet \
  --logtostderr=true \
  --v=0 \
  --api_servers=https://kube-master:6443 \
  --address=0.0.0.0 \
  --port=10250 \
  --allow-privileged=false \
  --tls-cert-file="/var/run/kubernetes/kubelet_client.crt" \
  --tls-private-key-file="/var/run/kubernetes/kubelet_client.key"
  --kubeconfig="/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig"
```

/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig is following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
users:
- name: kubelet
  user:
    client-certificate: /var/run/kubernetes/kubelet_client.crt
    client-key: /var/run/kubernetes/kubelet_client.key
clusters:
- name: kube-cluster
  cluster:
    certificate-authority: /var/run/kubernetes/ca.crt
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kube-cluster
    user: kubelet
  name: ctx-kube-system
current-context: ctx-kube-system
```

As I want to achieve the comunication using a two-way(both client and server)CA authentication and expect for a fluky reply,but apiserver ask me to provide my username and password which I have never used before,some command lines as following:

```
> kubectl version
> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"3", GitVersion:"v1.3.2", GitCommit:"9bafa3400a77c14ee50782bb05f9efc5c91b3185", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-07-17T18:30:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
> Please enter Username: kubelet
> Please enter Password: kubelet
> error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

I tried all these on master minion.Could anyone please resolve this conundrum？Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your opportune help!@SvenWalter:as supplement,`--client-ca-file` option already be used on the apiserver and I have tried to get nodes info using:

`curl https://kube-master:6443/api/v1/nodes --cert /var/run/kubernetes/server.crt --key /var/run/kubernetes/server.key --cacert /var/run/kubernetes/ca.crt`

so,maybe it not belong to a client certificate auth issue?The crt is a self signed file,does this metter?

Comment: The ca cert nay be self signed, but the client cert has to be signed by the ca cert.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable client certificate authorization via the `--client-ca-file` flag on the apiserver.

From http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/:

> **Client certificate authentication** is enabled by passing the `--client-ca-file=SOMEFILE` option to apiserver. The referenced file must contain one or more certificates authorities to use to validate client certificates presented to the apiserver. If a client certificate is presented and verified, the common name of the subject is used as the user name for the request.

From http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/:

> `--client-ca-file=""`: If set, any request presenting a client certificate signed by one of the authorities in the client-ca-file is authenticated with an identity corresponding to the CommonName of the client certificate.
>         `--cloud-config=""`: The path to the cloud provider configuration file.  Empty string for no configuration file.

Comment: also, on the kubelet side, `--tls-cert-file` and `--tls-private-key-file` in the kubelet args should reference the kubelet *serving* cert, not the client cert

Comment: @JordanLiggitt:yes,it's serving cert,I rename these files.because of the env(kubelet also be depolyed on master minion),I use the same CN for crt files.